# Setting a static final variable in constructor

Tags: java, static, constructor, final

what i basicly want is this:

```
public class Test 
{    
   private static final Integer a;

   public Test(Integer a) 
   {
      this.a = a;
   }
```

}

This obviously doesn't work, cause the 2nd created instance would try to override the final variable.
So is there a way to give all the instances the same immutable value via the constructor?

Comment: It's `static final`, so it's created once for all time and never changeable. Why is the constructor a reasonable place for this? (If it's due to a desire to lazily evaluate it, you may have make it non-final and rely on its private access control to prevent abuse.)

Comment: It's in the constructor cause the value depends on a config file value, but shouldn't be changed once it is set.

Comment: It sounds like you should just make the field not static.

Comment: If it's a global config setting (not specific to an instance), it should be set by a static initializer or static method, not the constructor. If it's an instance-specific setting, it should not be static (just final).

Comment: @RickyClarkson But wouldn't that be "wrong" or a memory waste, cause every instance will have the same variable with the same value instead of one variable for every instance?

Comment: Then perhaps you only want one instance of the class, and then there will be no waste.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Static final values should be initialized in a static context, not by instances.

One options is to set the value in the declaration:

```
private static final Integer a=FileConfig.getInstance().getA();
```

Each class can have a static {} block where code is called to initialize the static parts of the class.

```
static {
    a = FileConfig.getInstance().getA();
}
```

Finally, you can set the value from a static method

```
private static int getA() {
    return FileConfig.getInstance().getA();
}

private static final Integer a=getA();
```

In closure, static instance initialization does not belong in instance constructors.

If the configuration values change sometimes, there is simply no reason to store the value a in a static final variable. If you want to create each instance with the constant a in the constructor, what is the purpose of a static field in the first place? Somehow, when you call the constructor for the first time, you are passing in a value from ***somewhere***. If the value deserves to be static and final, you can acquire it from within the static initializer. If the configuration is not a singleton, but every instance always produces the same value of a, you could easily do `a = new FileConfig().getA();`.

Other than that, you could make the value non-final, and rest assured that since you always put in the same value of `a`, the static variable will not change.

Still, you could make `a` a final instance variable of the class, set in the constructor.

Comment: But the value isn't known at compilation time, it comes from a class that reads a config-file, thus i need a way to pass it to the Test class.

Comment: Why not have the static method simply ask for the value from the config file reading class?  It should be available at start-up, and the static initialization method will happily block while the config reader class loads its values.  I edited my examples.

Comment: The class which reads the configfiles isn't a singleton nor have static fields / methods, so sadly this isn't a solution :(

Comment: If the configuration values change sometimes, there is simply no reason to store the value a in a static final variable.  If you want to create each instance with the constant a in the constructor, what is the purpose of a static field?  Somehow, when you call the constructor for the first time, you are passing in a value from ***somewhere***.  If the value deserves to be static and final, you can acquire it from within the static initializer.  If the configuration is not a singleton, but every instance always produces the same value of a, you could easily do `a = new FileConfig().getA();`.

Comment: I basicly have an Arraylist of configFile objects (every file maps to a different type of object). Every configFile has a different "A" value. So there is no FileConfig().getA() but an ArrayList of FileConfig Instances with different values for "A". 1 ConfigFile belongs to many objects (all objects of a certain type). A Test instance is only created by a certain object type thus they all have the same "A" value and so there is no need for the Test class to have one "A" per instance.

Comment: Still, you could acquire the correct config object in the initializer.  Any java code can go there.  Without seeing your code, I can not tell you for certain, but it sounds like maybe a Singleton configuration object would be useful.  After all, a static variable ***is*** a Singleton.

Answer (score 2):

> So is there a way to give all the instances the same immutable value via the constructor?

I assume you want a value to be assigned to `a` the first time an object of type `Test` is created but not when any subsequent instance is created. In that case you cannot declare it `final`. `a` will be null initially, the constructor has to check if it is null and assign it a value in that case.

But I urge you to look at the design, especially why the caller have to provide the value. Isn't it counter-intuitive that after the second `Test` object is created Test.a does not change in the following case?

```
// assume this is the first `Test` object created:
Test t = new Test(5); // Test.a is 5
Test t = new Test(6); // Test.a is *still* 5
```